# Deleting from table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have this expense tracker website, it's just a beginner JavaScript project. I have an issue with deleting rows. If I click on the delete button it always deletes the first row below the heading, rather than deleting the row which I want to delete.
**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60cb322ae0.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>Expense Tracker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Expense Tracker</h1>
      <form action="">
        <label for="">Name</label>
        <input
          class="name"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Where was the expense made"
        /><br />
        <label for="">Date</label>
        <input class="date" type="date" />
        <label for="">Amount</label>
        <input class="amount" type="number" /><br />
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Add Expense</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
const name = document.querySelector(".name");
const date = document.querySelector(".date");
const amount = document.querySelector(".amount");
const btton = document.querySelector(".btn");
const table = document.querySelector("table");
//Event
btton.addEventListener("click", toTable);
table.addEventListener("click", toDelete);
//fucntion

function toTable(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //creating table row
  const tableRow = table.insertRow();
  //creating table definitions
  const tableName = tableRow.insertCell();
  const tableDate = tableRow.insertCell();
  const tableAmount = tableRow.insertCell();
  const tableDelete = tableRow.insertCell();
  tableDelete.classList.add("trash");
  //assigning values
  tableName.innerHTML = name.value;
  tableDate.innerHTML = date.value;
  tableAmount.innerHTML = amount.value;
  tableDelete.innerHTML = "<i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i>";
  //making the input fields clear
  name.value = "";
  date.value = "";
  amount.value = "";
}

function toDelete(event) {
  var item = document.querySelector(".trash");
  item = item.parentElement;
  item.remove();
}
```

Sorry for this mess of a code, I just started coding.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".trash")` selects the first element with that class in the document. You need to select the parent of the element that the event actually happened upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `document.querySelector(".trash")` it will fetch the first element on the page with a trash class. That is why the first row gets deleted.

What you should probably do is search for the parentElements class from the event you are getting.
Something like this:

```
function toDelete(event) {
  let row=event.target.closest(".parents-class");
  row.remove();
}
```

`event.target` will give you a reference to the object on which the event was dispatched. In your case this is probably the element that was clicked. From there we try to move up the DOM to the parent that we want to delete and then remove it.

Alternatively you could search for the closest `tr` tag and directly delete it that way:

```
function toDelete(event) {
  let row=event.target.closest("tr");
  row.remove();
}
```